# Who were the police of Vichy France?

Tags: world-war-two, france

I'm starting a small project with some friends, but before I got started, I wanted to make sure I had all my facts straight.

My question is about France in 1940, during the Second World War. When France was occupied by the Germans, who did they put in charge of the policing (in both the German Occupied Area, and Vichy France)? Was it just the German Army/Vichy French Forces? The SS?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Until the formal occupation of Vichy France in November, 1942, it had its own police force, based on what had existed before. But after the occupation, the Germans created the [Milice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milice), a French paramilitary police force under their control.